# Trouble understanding an eBPF (assembly) sample program from Prevail verifier

Tags: c, assembly, ebpf

I am looking at some of the Prevail eBPF verifier samples, more specifically this, https://github.com/vbpf/ebpf-samples/blob/bd5009255d9aa6bdccb3f7057126fa005456aaab/asm/byteswap.asm

The example is the following

```
; /home/alanjo/ebpf-verifier/ebpf-samples/src/byteswap.c:10
;    int rand32 = get_prandom_u32();
       0:   r0 = get_prandom_u32:7()
; /home/alanjo/ebpf-verifier/ebpf-samples/src/byteswap.c:12
;     if (rand32 & 0x01) {
       1:   r1 = r0
       2:   r1 &= 1
       3:   if r1 == 0 goto +3 <7>
; /home/alanjo/ebpf-verifier/ebpf-samples/src/byteswap.c:13
;         asm volatile("r0 = le64 r0\nexit");
       4:   r0 = le64 r0
       5:   exit
       6:   goto +25 <32>
; /home/alanjo/ebpf-verifier/ebpf-samples/src/byteswap.c:14
;     } else if (rand32 & 0x02) {
       7:   r1 = r0
       8:   r1 &= 2
       9:   if r1 == 0 goto +3 <13>
; /home/alanjo/ebpf-verifier/ebpf-samples/src/byteswap.c:15
;         asm volatile("r0 = le32 r0\nexit");
      10:   r0 = le32 r0
      11:   exit
      12:   goto +19 <32>
; /home/alanjo/ebpf-verifier/ebpf-samples/src/byteswap.c:16
;     } else if (rand32 & 0x04) {
      13:   r1 = r0
      14:   r1 &= 4
      15:   if r1 == 0 goto +3 <19>
; /home/alanjo/ebpf-verifier/ebpf-samples/src/byteswap.c:17
;         asm volatile("r0 = le16 r0\nexit");
      16:   r0 = le16 r0
      17:   exit
      18:   goto +13 <32>
; /home/alanjo/ebpf-verifier/ebpf-samples/src/byteswap.c:18
;     } else if (rand32 & 0x10) {
      19:   r1 = r0
      20:   r1 &= 16
      21:   if r1 == 0 goto +3 <25>
; /home/alanjo/ebpf-verifier/ebpf-samples/src/byteswap.c:19
;         asm volatile("r0 = be64 r0\nexit");
      22:   r0 = be64 r0
      23:   exit
      24:   goto +7 <32>
; /home/alanjo/ebpf-verifier/ebpf-samples/src/byteswap.c:20
;     } else if (rand32 & 0x20) {
      25:   r0 &= 32
      26:   if r0 == 0 goto +3 <30>
; /home/alanjo/ebpf-verifier/ebpf-samples/src/byteswap.c:21
;         asm volatile("r0 = be32 r0\nexit");
      27:   r0 = be32 r0
      28:   exit
      29:   goto +2 <32>
; /home/alanjo/ebpf-verifier/ebpf-samples/src/byteswap.c:23
;         asm volatile("r0 = be16 r0\nexit");
      30:   r0 = be16 r0
      31:   exit
; /home/alanjo/ebpf-verifier/ebpf-samples/src/byteswap.c:25
;     return 0;
      32:   r0 = 0
      33:   exit
```

It seems to me that the `goto` statements on line 6, 12, 18, 24 and 29 are redundant? E.g, the control flow from line 3 meets the `exit` on line 5, and thus exits the program, or it jumps to line 7, thus line 6 is never hit?

I am I misunderstanding something, does the `exit` behave differently to my expectations?

Note that the corresponding C code is inlined as comments

Comment: The compiler doesn't analyze the contents of `asm` blocks so it doesn't recognize the `exit`.

Comment: So the `exit`'s are redundant? Or how am I to interpret your comment?

Comment: No, the `goto`s are redundant, as you said. The compiler does not know about the `exit` so it assumes execution reaches the end of the `asm` block so it has to jump out from the conditional.

Comment: But then this does also mean that the last two lines (32,33) are redundant, since if the `goto`s are redundant, then there are no paths to line 32 and 33?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Again, the compiler does not know that the last block has an `exit` so it assumes execution can reach the `return 0`.